# How to add character to the end of the line in node js or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file that has 6,000 of json. Its raw data and I need to add an comma ' , ' to the end of each line. Can someone help. Current code is creating a new line with a comma I need comma at end of each line. Node js or Javascript example is acceptable

The data file:

```
{"id": "67", "ac": []}
{"id": "78","ac": []}
{"id": "90", "ac": []}
```

What I am currently getting:

```
{"id": "67", "ac": []}
,
{"id": "78","ac": []}
,
{"id": "90", "ac": []}
```

What I need

```
{"id": "67", "ac": []},
{"id": "78","ac": []},
{"id": "90", "ac": []},
```

Current code

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile("users.json", (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let student = data.toString();

  var lines = student.split(/(\n|\r\n)/);

  var new_content = lines
    .map(function (line) {
      return line + ",";
    })
    .join("\r\n");
  fs.writeFile("newFile.json", new_content, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Data written to file");
  });
```

Comment: Where is this "JSON" coming from? How are you making it? You really should be fixing it at that point.

Comment: It's a user file. users.json.  I have no way to correct data at source. It was giving to me as string data. each line represent json line

Comment: Part of your issue: `split(/(\n|\r\n)/)` gets you the content of one line, then an element containing _just_ the line break, then the content of the next line, and so on, alternatingly. Remove the grouping braces: `/\n|\r\n/` - then the resulting array will contain only the line contents, without the "only line break" elements in between.

Comment: And then you can probably do away with the mapping completely, if you just `join` your array together again with `",\r\n"`

Comment: Or don't split to begin with, and instead _replace_ your matched line breaks with `,\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like your trying to mutate a string by adding the comma in the map function. 'line' is immutable so you cant add the comma, but you can reassign the value; I.E line = line += ',' or newValue = line += ',' then return the value after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).